# Wordpress multisite admin lockout

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

...I gave in to the nagging message from Jetpack last week to turn on "Protect" and the day after, I found myself unable to log in to the admin dashboard. (I'm not 100% certain that Jetpack is at fault here, but it's the most obvious thing that changed.)

Symptom is that wp-admin is not available for any of my sub-sites.

I've tried the usual things (IP whitelist, adding IP to the config file, disabling the suspicious plugin, disabling all the plugins) but the behavior remains the same.

Any login attempt will fail, and I'll see a redirect to the login page. Here's the URI pattern for the redirect:

```
http://myclientsite.domain.us/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%myclientsite.domain.us%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

I thought to address it at the database level, but inspecting the database, I do not see any user table. (I'm led to believe that the user table should be global to the installation and contain user info for all sites)

So my two questions are:

How can I find the user table for my site? I've logged in to the database directly both with the wordpress user account and with the root account. Don't see the table in either case.

What can I change about the installation that would allow me to at least access the admin functions and disable the offending plugin?

Comment: More data -- after spinning up a new EC2 instance from the same AMI, I get a database that looks like this: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1827FTsLfAMUDhDSV90S25tVmM/view?usp=sharing)  The users table is called "wp_users" -- but in my original (problem) installation, there are no pure "wp_XXX" tables. I see only the ones that are tagged as belonging to a sub-site (ie. they are called "wp_X_xxxxx" where X is the subsite instance identifier) -- here's what that looks like: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1827FTsLfAMUFhjdUVyRjY4SEU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I finally stood up a new multisite instance and imported a safe backup (using Updraft Plus to backup and restore in this case).

I did not resolve the lockout issue, but I found the answer to another mystery I was wrestling with. The user table WAS present, but my superficial understanding of phpMyAdmin kept me from seeing it. (Shoulda used the mysql cli client)

It turns out that in the table browser on the left hand margin (navigation panel), the table list is paged, and I was looking only at the first page.

So each subordinate site has table name prefixes that look like wp_X_ where X is the subdomain index within the multisite structure. The "primary" site has data in tables that simply use wp_ and that's the one that hosts the user table.

For me then, the trick was to notice that in the phpMyAdmin navigation panel, I could page to the next set of tables and there was the table I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To get into wp-admin, you can disable all plugins by renaming the plugins folder that is in the wp-content folder.

Comment: ...ummm, I think in my original post, I indicated that I had tried that measure.

`I've tried the usual things (IP whitelist, adding IP to the config file, disabling the suspicious plugin, disabling all the plugins)`

I've tried the easy things.

What I'm looking for is someone who can explain why I might not see the "users" table when I inspect the database, or why Jetpack Protect might do something that we didn't expect.